# How to check when the map execution is over in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs, css, react-router

```
**{data.listArts.items.map((art, index) => {
                    return (
                      <a className="thumbnail" key={index}>
                        <img src={art.ArtURL}/>
                      </a>
                    );})}**
```

I have this code for showing multiple items in the UI. data.listArts.items contains around 100 elements.

I want to call a function when this map execution is over so that the function which I am call can work with the rendered HTML in reactJS.

Comment: Is map really async? Otherwise just run your other code immediately after.

Comment: @powerbuoy yes the map is async.

Comment: Naw, map isn't async. Perhaps you're performing async tasks inside your map callback but map itself is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map doesn't have a callback (when it has reached the end of an array) but you can always check if the last element is reached and invoke a function.

```js
const length = data.listArts.items.length
data.listArts.items.map((art, index) => {
if(index === length -1) {
 /* invoke callback */
}
return (
  <a className="thumbnail" key={index}>
    <img src={art.ArtURL}/>
  </a>
);})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check length of an array with index

```
   data.listArts.items.map((art, index) => {
               if(data.listArts.items.length -1 == index){
                      //do what you want to do here may be a flag set here
               }
                return (
                  <a className="thumbnail" key={index}>
                    <img src={art.ArtURL}/>
                  </a>
                );}

     )}
```